# Why hipothesis of perfect competition market implies fixed price of a product in every transaction?

Tags: microeconomics, efficient-markets

My book says that from the axioms of perfect competition follows that the price is fixed in every transaction but it doesn't specify in which way it is possible to prove it. Besides, are all the axioms necessary to prove this "theorem"?

Comment: What axioms are you taking about?

Comment: The hypothesis of perfect competition market